# convexity of special structure function

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-definite

Let $A\in S_n$ be positive definite. Prove the convexity of the function 
$$
f(x):=\left<Ax,x\right>\left<A^{-1}x,x\right>
$$

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: eigenvalue problem

Comment: I was asking what you have done till now to solve this problem...

Comment: Let $A = P^T\Sigma P$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix, and set $g(x) = \left<\Sigma x, x\right>  \left<\Sigma^{-1} x, x\right>$, and we have $f(x) = g(Px)$. I try to prove that $g$ is convex, and then $f$ is convex, that is what i think.

Comment: It is false in general. See (https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0734). Important keyword for expression $f(x)$ : "Kantorovich"

Comment: Thanks! I think i understand